# Sending notifications on build start in Bamboo server

Tags: bamboo

I'm looking to be able to send notification whenever a build is started and not only when they are completed.

Is there a way to get custom Notification Events?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a native way to do this.  However, there are some creative ways to get around this:

1. Use a task in a build job to send out the notification via a script or executable (my recommendation).
2. Use webhooks and 3rd party applications (e.g., Slack, Microsoft Teams)
3. Use the Bamboo API + a custom script to watch for the build to start.

Comment: Do you have an example in how to use webhooks for achieve that?

Comment: It's not free but Slack Task for Bamboo will use a webhook to communicate with a Slack channel.  Another example would be use a Bamboo task to send a message through the webhook for the platform of your choice.  Here's the link to Slack via a webhook post: https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks